# How to make a fancybox lightbox appear on page load

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi I need some help making a fancybox lightbox open on page load.

Here is my [example page](http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach%20horizon/lighttest.html)

What I am trying to acheive is having a lightbox open on page load with an html page, such as an iframe, within the lightbox.

My js call is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(

        {
      'autoDimensions'  : false,
      'width'               : 350,
      'height'              : 650,
      'transitionIn'        : 'none',
      'transitionOut'       : 'none',
      'type': 'iframe',
      'href': 'http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach%20horizon/lighttest.html'
        }
    );
});
```

Lightbox does load so the js is ok but my html page doesn't load within the window. Any help is appreciated.

Thx
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but you have fancybox called twice: once minified and once full source

```
<!-- HERE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<!-- AND HERE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/fancyboxcall.js"></script>
```

It's also more readable to use relative paths (I thought you were linking externally):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach horizon/js/fancyboxcall.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit your version of `fancybox.js` file? it seems to be corrupted. Try downloading it and re-install it again.

You get this error:

```
Timestamp: 11/05/2012 11:29:38 AM
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: http://www.meandhimclients.co.uk/beachhorizon/bh_wordpressdev/wp-content/themes/beach%20horizon/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js
Line: 45
Source Code:
b.fn.fancybox.defaults={padding:10,margin:40,opacity:false,modal:false,cyclic:false,scrolling:"auto",width:560,height:340,autoScale:true,autoDimensions:true,centerOnScroll:false,ajax:{},swf:{wmode:"transparent"},hideOnOverlayClick:true,hideOnContentClick:false,overlayShow:true,overlayOpacity:0.7,overlayColor:"#777",titleShow:true,titlePosition:"float",titleFormat:null,titleFromAlt:false,transitionIn:"fade",transitionOut:"fade",speedIn:300,speedOut:300,changeSpeed:300,changeFade:"fast",easingIn:"swing",
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Fancybox an image viewer and not an iframe popup? If you wanted an iFrame to popup, you could create a border image and then make an iframe in it, and then in the `document.ready` function, make it appear with a fade, something like this:

```
document.ready(function(){
  $("lightbox").fadeIn();
});
```